# alertdialogbox should popup from the bottom of the screen?

Tags: android, dialog, alert

I have an alert dialog box in my application.i want the alert dialog box to pop up from the bottom of the screen.can anyone help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had done this customizing a dialog and adding a animated theme to the dialog. Its was so simple just passing the animation to the constructor of the dialog and calling the super function with the theme(Animation) will make this happen. Thankzz for all your help....happy coding....

Answer (score 1):

[Animation Api](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/index.html) may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

check this answer [slide animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305581/how-to-make-a-dialog-slide-from-bottom-to-middle-of-screen-in-android/9305731#9305731). Its like a iphone actionsheet sliding from bottom to center of the screen