# How to make a dialog slide from bottom to middle of screen in android

Tags: android

I want to show a dialog on my activity with animation. My dialog will slide from bottom of activity to middle of activity.

/****Edit****/

I'm sorry for my question is unclear. I mean that my dialog will be slide from bottom to middle but the bottom side of dialog is placed on bottom side of activity , like this following picture[image]

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/SlidingDrawer which makes it possible to slide from any side by few lines of code.

Comment: i do not see an example, you have given a layout xml but how to use it in the code ? can u please give an example ?

Comment: This is outdated for most people, but still it's worth noting for newcomers - *do not* replicate iOS experience on Android. See Material Design guidelines to see what should and should not be done, as suggested by Google (https://material.io).

Answer (score 178, accepted):

For this, you need 2 animations and put this in the res/anim folder

1. slide_up_dialog.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:fromYDelta="50%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
>     android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
> ```

2.slide_out_down.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
>     android:fromYDelta="0%p"
>     android:toYDelta="100%p" />
> ```

Now you have to create a custom style in style.xml

```
<style name="DialogAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up_dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_down</item>
</style>
```

Next is to extend the android Theme. Dialog theme in the same style.xml and give the reference to the custom style we created.

```
<!-- Animation for dialog box -->
    <style name="DialogSlideAnim" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogAnimation</item>
    </style>
```

And finally, call this style when you create the dialog like this.

```
dialog = new Dialog(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.DialogSlideAnim));
```

yep...Now the Dialog is ready to slide.....!!

**Update:**

As @MichealP suggested, this will place the window at the bottom

```
getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

and modify the style to remove tittle and background

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item> 
<item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item> 
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

As @sikni8 suggested this will make the black border transparent

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: i added getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM); and  <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>       <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> And then it works as i desired

Comment: @MichaelP Is is not coming from bottom for me. It just start animation like grow_from_middle but on bottom of screen. IS there something that I missed.

Comment: You can also use `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);` to make the black border transparent at runtime.

Comment: Hello @arunsoorya, i implemented your solution to animate the Dialog but then i implemented the "Android Action Bar Style Generator" files and the Theme that it generated and now the Style used to create the Dialog "hintDialog = new Dialog(c, R.style.DialogSlideAnim);" is showing the dialog with a transparent background.. what should I fix? thanks :)

Comment: If you're using appcompat-v7 you don't need the two animation xml files. Instead of using @anim/slide_up_dialog use @anim/abc_slide_in_bottom. And instead of using @anim/slide_out_down you can use @anim/abc_slide_out_bottom.

Comment: somehow it does not covers whole width of the screen ? what shall I do to make it cover whole width of screen when dialog box appears from bottom ? Thanks

Comment: This is the kind of answers that everybody would love to find on Stackoverflow. Thank you.

Comment: For me dialog = new Dialog(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.DialogSlideAnim)); didnt work.. instead I used this - dialog.getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.DialogAnimation);

Comment: Dialog width is not full. Please suggest for set actual width.

Answer (score 22):

I tried all the answers in here and it don't work for me. I know all that answers are written long time ago. So let me show how I get it to work.
 [I followed this article.](http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/10/showing-dialog-with-animation-in-android.html)

In short :
create res/anim/slide_up.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate 
      android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" 
      android:fromYDelta="100%" 
      android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
      android:toYDelta="0">
    </translate>
</set>
```

then, create res/anim/slide_bottom.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate 
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" 
        android:fromYDelta="0%p" 
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
        android:toYDelta="100%p">
    </translate>
</set>
```

Then add a style in res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up_dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_down</item>
</style>
```

Now you can set this animation style to your dialog or alertdialog box like below.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = animationSource;
```

Or,

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
lp.windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

I showed example only for dialog boxes, but as I said before you can use this method for alert dialog boxes too.

Comment: yes this is the perfect answer which i found working from all here.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a **Modal Bottom Sheet** ([reference](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-dialog-fragment/)).

1. Add the design support library

   ```
   implementation "com.android.support:design:$version_support"
   ```
2. Create a `Fragment` that extends `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and override `onCreateView`

   ```
   class BottomDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() { 

       companion object {
           fun newInstance() = BottomDialogFragment()
       }

       override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
           return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, container)
       }
   }
   ```
3. Show the dialog

   ```
   val dialog = BottomDialogFragment.newInstance()
   dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, BottomDialogFragment::class.java.simpleName)
   ```

Comment: how to send data in BottomDIalogFragment ?

Comment: The same way you do with a regular Fragment, you create a Bundle and put data there

Answer (score 5):

you can use bottom Sheets. I put some infromation about it.

With Android Support Library 23.2, Google announced support for Bottom Sheets. According to Material Design, Bottom Sheets are elements displayed only as a result of a user-initiated action, used to reveal more content.

There are two major types of bottom sheets:

***Modal bottom sheets*** are alternatives to menus or simple dialogs. They can also present deep-linked content from other apps. They are primarily for mobile.

***Persistent bottom sheets*** present in-app content

There is simple example

Making a BottomSheet on Android is quite easy, you just have to use a ***CoordinatorLayout*** as main element of your layout and attach a BottomSheet behavior to a view.

**1 step** - activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnButtonSheet"
    android:text="Camera"
    android:textColor="#1e1e1e"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<!-- Adding bottom sheet after main content -->
<include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**2 step** - add bottom_sheet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:behavior_hideable="true"
app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select your options!"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#1e1e1e"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPhoto"
    android:text="Photo"
    android:textColor="#1e1e1e"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCamera"
    android:text="Camera"
    android:textColor="#1e1e1e"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:background="#a2a2a3"
    android:textColor="#1e1e1e"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**3 step** - make your MainActivity like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.btnButtonSheet)
Button btnBottomSheet;

@BindView(R.id.bottom_sheet)
LinearLayout layoutBottomSheet;

BottomSheetBehavior sheetBehavior;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    sheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(layoutBottomSheet);


    sheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            switch (newState) {
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED: {
                    btnBottomSheet.setText("Close");
                }
                break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED: {
                    btnBottomSheet.setText("Expand");
                }
                break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:
                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        }
    });
}

@OnClick(R.id.btnButtonSheet)
public void toggleBottomSheet() {
    if (sheetBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
        sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        btnBottomSheet.setText("Close Bottom sheet");
    } else {
        sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        btnBottomSheet.setText("Expand Bottom sheet");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: To newcomers - there is a use-case for when it's **not** a good idea to use bottom sheets - for example when you don't want dialogs to be dismissable by pulling down with your finger. One use-case would be a list of items where you use a ItemTouchHelper on each item - in that case you need to override so many methods  from BottomSheetDialog, it becomes pointless to use a done solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simplest way to animate dialog when showing

```
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        View view = dialog.getWindow().getDecorView();
        //for enter from left
        //ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", -view.getWidth(), 0.0f).start(); 

        //for enter from bottom
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", view.getHeight(), 0.0f).start();
    }

});
```

In addition to it, make dialog background full screen and transparent when animating from bottom

```
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Answer (score 1):

The new Material Design library gives you the [BottomSheetDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog) for that exact look and easier implementation

Answer (score 0):

In addition to arunsoorya's answer :

Change **slide_up_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />
```

And **slide_out_down.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" 
    android:toYDelta="50%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to all other answer, you can use this animation for top bar.
Refrence  from here  https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-slide-up-down-animations-with-examples

**slide_up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0" />
</set>
```

**slide_down.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

The output looks like this

[image]