# Android windowEnterAnimation attribute does not exist

Tags: android, android-animation, android-styles

I've been trying to follow this answer for [adding an animation to a dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305581/how-to-make-a-dialog-slide-from-bottom-to-middle-of-screen-in-android).  However I'm getting an error on the first style addition.

I've added the following to `res/values/styles.xml` (not completely sure if this is correct)

```
<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_down_dialog.xml</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_up</item>
</style>
```

The first item, `android:windowEnterAnimation`, does not seem to exist when I tab complete `android:`.  This also applies to `android:windowExitAnimation`.  The error I receive in the XML file is:

`error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:windowEnterAnimation' with value '@anim/slide_down_dialog.xml').`

All the questions I've found regarding animation like this uses `windowEnter/ExitAnimation`.  I looked at the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html) and it supposedly has this attribute, but I cannot for the life of me get it to appear.

Thanks in advance for any help/advice.  If this is a duplicate please point me in the right direction, I couldn't find any related questions.

Comment: have you fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

you sholud put `@` letter before android and remove the `.xml` like:

```
<item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_down_dialog</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is:
remove (.xml) to be like (@anim/slide_down_dialog)