# Custom alert dialog android

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-custom-view, android-alertdialog, customdialog

I am working with custom alert dialog in android.

I have followed the [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467026/change-dialog-position-on-the-screen) and [linke 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305581/how-to-make-a-dialog-slide-from-bottom-to-middle-of-screen-in-android).

In my code using these styles.

```
<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up_dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_down</item>
```

```
<!-- Animation for dialog box -->
<style name="DialogSlideAnim" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogAnimation</item>
</style>
```

From these styles I am getting bordered dialog. But I need like the below.[image: Custom alert dialog]

I am using LG Nexus 4 device. What should I have to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have some solution. Please look at the example below.

In style xml use this:

```
<resources>
    ....
    <style name="DialogAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/abc_slide_in_bottom</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/abc_slide_out_bottom</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogSlideAnim">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogAnimation</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And dialog layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Male"
            android:id="@+id/male"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"
            android:id="@+id/female"
            android:layout_below="@id/male"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_below="@id/female"
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And dialog java file:

```
public class YourDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.DialogSlideAnim);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_dialog, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        final Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        window.setAttributes(lp);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, still I am getting the white color backgroud.

Comment: try add android:background=@android:color/transparent in your RelativeLayout in dialog layout But it is strange for me because in my test app everything works fine

Comment: On which api level do you test it?

Comment: I am using API level 20

Comment: Give me a few minutes I will check it

Comment: I tested my solution on empty project. I created  activity with red background it is what I get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70907/discussion-between-konrad-krakowiak-and-karthikeyan-ve).

Comment: Ya sure... we will continue with chat.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. I have used Dialog instead AlertDialog.Builder. Its working.

Comment: That's great I am glad that I could help you.