# Access buttons in custom alert dialog

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog

I have created a custom alert dialog using the following code -

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null))
       .setTitle("test")
       .setCancelable(true);

AlertDialog alert11 = builder.create();
alert11.show();
```

Here is the code of the layout dialog.xml which is used in the alert dialog -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, how to get a reference of the button to set a click listener?

I tried this -

```
Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

but I get an exception -

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Is there any other way to access the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for the button in the wrong place.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
builder.setView(view)
       .setTitle("test")
       .setCancelable(true);
```

and then use `view` to look for your buotton

Answer (score 1):

You can access a Button Like this way

```
Button dialogButton = (Button) alert11.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Answer (score 1):

U can customize full alert dialog as per requirement.. check this answer.. [Android - change dialog button location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942141/android-change-dialog-button-location/29942452#29942452)

Answer (score 1):

First inflate your custom view as

```
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
```

then use `dialoglayout` as

```
  builder.setView(dialoglayout)
   .setTitle("test")
   .setCancelable(true);
```

and now find button as

```
Button mButton = (Button) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Answer (score 1):

in your case use

```
Button mButton = (Button)(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null)). findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code which will solve your problem-

```
View view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setView(view);
final AlertDialog mDialog = builder.create();
mDialog.setCancelable(false);

Button mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
mDialog.show();
```