# AlertDialog action button placement

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I've created an `AlertDialog` using the `AlertDialog.Builder` and would like to adjust the placement of the action buttons (Cancel and OK) to improve its appearance.

I've searched and can't seem to find any easy way. Do I have to abandon the `AlertDialog.Builder` and add the action button functions to my view and setup all the listeners?  If so, how do I determine the text size/color for the action buttons to stay consistent with other `AlertDialog`?

[image: Screenshot of the popup]

`popup_tee_selection_edittext.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/popup_tee_selection_TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/enter_new_tee"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/popup_tee_selection_EditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/popup_tee_selection_Switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|start"
    android:showText="true"
    android:textOff="Men"
    android:textOn="Women"
    android:thumbTextPadding="10dp"
    android:thumb="@drawable/custom_switch_inner_holo_light"
    android:track="@drawable/custom_switch_track_holo_light"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

code fragment

```
private void popupTeeSelectionEditText() {
    View popupView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.popup_tee_selection_edittext, null);
    final EditText userInput = (EditText) popupView.findViewById(R.id.popup_tee_selection_EditText);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setView(popupView)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    String selectedItem = userInput.getText().toString();
                    if (DEBUG) Log.w(TAG, "Returned value: '" + selectedItem + "'");
                    if (listViewAlertDialog != null)
                        listViewAlertDialog.cancel();
                    processTeeSelectionCourse(selectedItem);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```

Comment: Hi. What exactly is the final output you are looking for ? The buttons to line up with the "men" switch ?

Comment: Exactly.  In my screenshot the blue line indicates where I like the bottom of the dialog to be and action buttons would be aligned with the switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the view that one supplies to the dialog's builder is only for the central section of the dialog, without the Title section at the top and the button section at the bottom. To get a look that you are aiming for, you'll need to add your custom buttons to this view, setup the appropriate listeners, and then hide the original buttons.

To setup the color to match, check what the app's primary and accent colors are. If none are specified, you could set them to android defaults, or probably specify them in the app theme settings so that all dialogs in the app will carry the same look.

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31514677/1277178) to checkout how to setup custom colors for the dialog buttons.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions. Time to customize the entire dialog!

Answer (score 1):

The `AlertDialog` method [getButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#getButton(int)) can be used to get an action button after the dialog has been created. You can then change the textSize, textColor etc as you want. I don't think you'll be able to change it's position though.

To position the buttons precisely relative to your other content views you'll need to add them yourself instead, in your `popupView`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched through other similar questions on stack overflow?

Here are a few with solutions that maybe able to help you out. Links are below.

- [Android - change dialog button location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942141/android-change-dialog-button-location)
- [Android Alertdialog Example: Creating Your Own Alerts](https://blog.udemy.com/android-alertdialog-examples/)

For the second link, scroll all the way down to the bottom where they briefly discuss about creating your own custom dialog boxes. With custom dialog boxes you should be able to get the format you want.

The getButton() method mentioned by Sound Conception may also be a viable method.

Comment: Yes, as I stated in my initial question, I've searched but can't find an easy way.  Thanks for the links.

Comment: @DaveFite, no problem! Glad to see your question has been resolved =).