# Custom layout files for alert dialog

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm trying to use a *custom layout file* for an **alert dialog** on android (support library version 26.1.0)

I've tried using the following:

```
<style name="MyTheme"...>
  <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/MyTheme.AlertDialog</item>
</styles>

<style name="MyTheme.AlertDialog" parent="Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/custom_abc_alert_dialog_material</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/MyTheme.Button.Negative</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/MyTheme.Button.Neutral</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/MyTheme.Button.Positive</item>
</style>
```

I can tell it's picking up the actual theme, as the button styles are updated.  However, it's not picking up the custom layout file.  I see this code in **AlertController** in the support library:

```
    mAlertDialogLayout = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.AlertDialog_android_layout, 0);
```

which translates back to the source:

```
<declare-styleable name="AlertDialog">
  <attr name="android:layout"/>
  ...
</declare-styleable>
```

I also see this in the support library *values.xml* file:

```
<style name="Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/abc_alert_dialog_material</item>
```

I suspect my usage of `android:layout` is not being picked up due to the above styleable declaration.  I just have no idea how to overcome that and properly specify the layout.

I realize I could use a custom view and use setView on the dialog, but that's intrusive when all I want to do is re-arrange a few things on the layout (which can't be controlled with theme attributes sadly enough)

I also realize I could just replace *abc_alert_dialog_material.xml* entirely, but then it's replaced for all themes, not just the one I'm working with.

Does anyone have any idea what I might be missing here to properly use my custom layout file? ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484621/custom-alert-dialog-android

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  I want an alert dialog, not a DialogFragment.   The AlertDialog class is a Dialog subclass, not a fragment.  DialogFragment has a bunch of baggage that i really don't want to deal with.  Plus I want exactly the functionality that AlertDialog has, just slightly altered visuals.

Comment: The `DialogFragment` part doesn't matter. The answer still shows how to use a `style` with a custom dialog layout.

Comment: If that particular answer doesn't do it for you there are probably about 20 other questions related to the custom alert dialogs. It looks like you're trying to combine the style with the layout, they should be separate. There's no need to mess with the support library files.

Comment: I understand how to set the style, and as I mentioned, it is set appropriately, otherwise my button styles would not have changed.  However, what's not working is changing the layout via the style, which in theory should work, provided i can find the right attribute to put in there so that this statement gives me back my layout:  a.getResourceId(R.styleable.AlertDialog_android_layout, 0)

Comment: And based on the xml provided in the support library android:layout should be the right attribute.  This is the crux of my question.  Maybe that only works because it's within the support library itself, I don't know.  That's why i'm asking.

Comment: any solution? where this custom styleable available?