# How to make dialog to slide up and exit from current position?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I need to translate dialog from current position to top as exit animation. In the presence of keyboard it will be available at top and should translate and exit from that position, incase if keyboard is not visible it will be in centre and should exit from there.

Tried the below snippet:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillBefore="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true">
    <translate
        android:duration="400"
        android:toYDelta="-100%p"
     />
</set>
```

In this case when the dialog is not at centre (when keyboard is visible), it comes down once (to its centre position) and then translates up. This causes flickering. What am i doing wrong? How to translate smoothly

Comment: could you fix this problem? i have same problem

Answer (score 1):

slideup.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0"
        android:duration="500"/>
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="-100%" android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

style.xml :

```
    <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyAnimation.Window</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyAnimation.Window" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
    </style>
```

on your code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogTheme);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to show the custom dialog up and down.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="100%p" />

</set>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="50%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p" />

</set>
```

Comment: this is similar to what i have done. It doesn't work out

Comment: refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305581/how-to-make-a-dialog-slide-from-bottom-to-middle-of-screen-in-android for more info