# How to create half-window view menu?

Tags: android, material-design

How can I implement the above view? (not the whole menu) but a similar exmaple.

I want to open up this half-window like menu by the click of a button, if this is possible.

[image: Picture]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'e looking for BottomSheet. It's provided now as part of the support libraries. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721403/android-how-to-implement-bottom-sheet-from-material-design-docs/35615022#35615022 and http://android-developers.blogspot.mx/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats what I was looking for! Im gonna try it out!

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at DialogFragment in the android dev docs.
then I think this question below could help :)

[How to make a dialog slide from bottom to middle of screen in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305581/how-to-make-a-dialog-slide-from-bottom-to-middle-of-screen-in-android)

Comment: Thanks I ll try it out, and feedback :)